# Error in google colab(python) while transliterating data into Indian language

Tags: python, google-colaboratory, emoji, transliteration

I am transliterating data into India language using python in google colab, but encountered error:
*AttributeError: module 'emoji' has no attribute 'UNICODE_EMOJI'*

The error occurs to the second line in the code:

```
for word in line_list: 
            if word in emoji.UNICODE_EMOJI:
                new_line_list.append(emoji.demojize(word))
```

emoji package in installed and imported version is 2.0.0

Answer (score 6):

You can use the function `distinct_emoji_list()` to extract emojis in a string and return a list of found emojis, then call `emoji.demojize()` on each emoji in that list to convert it into its meaning.

so having:

```
line_list = ['Hello World! ', 'Goodbye World ']
new_line_list = []

for word in line_list:
  emojis = emoji.distinct_emoji_list(word)
  new_line_list.extend([emoji.demojize(is_emoji) for is_emoji in emojis])
```

Printing new_line_list would give

```
[':grinning_face_with_smiling_eyes:', ':grinning_face_with_sweat:']
```

Answer (score 2):

latest version of emoji==2.1.0 has no attribute Unicode_emoji.
So, try to uninstall the existing version and install emoji==1.7.0

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I found this `emoji.UNICODE_EMOJI` and `emoji.UNICODE_EMOJI['en]` as an error.
So, I got it solved using `emoji.distinct_emoji_list(test)`
where, `test` is a string.
**cheers!**

Answer (score 0):

In the latest version of emoji the property UNICODE_EMOJI has been removed in version 2.0.0.

You can try to use `EMOJI_DATA` as a replacement for `UNICODE_EMOJI`. If you explain how you use `UNICODE_EMOJI`.

You can also downgrade the module version to emoji~=1.6.3 and stay with the old version that has the `UNICODE_EMOJI` property.